Error in GoogleTagManager with NextJS - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'getValue' on 'CookieDeprecationLabel': Illegal invocation
This is my first time integrating GoogleTagManager into my website Portfolio for Google Analytics. I'm using NextJS for this project. But when I deploy it or run it in local, I get the following error.
js?id=G-WTK6KTMQ7Z:360 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'getValue' on 'CookieDeprecationLabel': Illegal invocation
    at nl (js?id=G-WTK6KTMQ7Z:360:331)
    at js?id=G-WTK6KTMQ7Z:758:6
    at c (js?id=G-WTK6KTMQ7Z:755:130)
    at js?id=G-WTK6KTMQ7Z:757:382
    at js?id=G-WTK6KTMQ7Z:757:387
    at js?id=G-WTK6KTMQ7Z:768:3

This seems to be an issue with GoogleTagManager Script given by Google Analytics. This is my layout.tsx file containing the script.
import Script from "next/script";
/* other imports */

const jetbrainsMono = JetBrains_Mono({/* options */});

export const metadata: Metadata = {/* metadata */};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <Script id="google-analytics" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-WTK6KTMQ7Z" strategy="beforeInteractive"></Script>
      <Script id="google-analytics" strategy="beforeInteractive">
        {`
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'G-WTK6KTMQ7Z');
      `}</Script>
      </head>
      <body className={jetbrainsMono.variable}>
        <Header/>
        <StairTransition/>
        <PageTrainsition>
          {children}
        </PageTrainsition>
        <Toaster/>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

The error seems to originate from here.

I tried disabling the AdBlockers from chrome extensions. But it didn't help.

See this post: ga4 gtag.js started showing error in Chrome
Looks like an issue on how GTM interact with chrome privacy sandbox features. I tested with your website, and I can replicate the issue when I enabled the 3P cookie phase out testing option on my chrome, but the issue didn't present when I disable the testing.
This issue has already been reported to Google so maybe let's just wait for bit to see if the team is going to fix it.

Yes the error did not persist when I disabled Third-party Cookie Phase Out Facilitated Testing from chrome://flags/ . Thanks.
